# Is there a common way to implement invariants?

Tags: c++, invariants

This is a basic example where i want to add intvariants, for example that my age can't be under 0.

```
#include "InvariantTest.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int age;
string name;


void setAge(int a) {
    age = a;
}

void setName(string n) {
    name = n;
}

string getNameandAge() {
    string both;

    both = name + to_string(age);
    return both;

}
```

I can't find a norm how to implement invariants in c++.

Comment: what "norm" are you looking for? In `setAge` you unconditionally assign the age, if you want it only if it is `>0` then you need something like `if (a > 0) age = a;`

Comment: But if i only use a `if` statement to make sure that my age cant be under 0, does it count as a invariant?

Comment: do you know what an invariant is? Read eg the tag description...

Comment: Btw if your age can't be negative you might want to make it unsigned.

Comment: @bipll *if* your age can't be negative, how many -50yr olds do you know :p, but i'd say don't make it unsigned, because then there's no way of knowing if a negative age does get passed as an argument, you'd only be able to check really large ages

Comment: @Nick I don't know much about them, but I suspect that some people will be born in 2070.

Comment: @eerorika ... touché

Comment: @Nick "no way of knowing if a negative age get passed as an argument"...slightly different topic, but sure there is a way

Comment: An invariant is nothing more than a promise by the programmer to never break certain rules. As long as you never call `setAge` with `a<0` you have an invariant. To test for the invariant, just do a normal `if`-test and call `exit` or `abort` on failure. No need for a runtime "fix" of the error, as you have just proved that the program is in a broken unknown state.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Well yes, you could cast the unsigned to a signed and see if it's negative, or check if it's value is above the threshold to be negative if it were signed, but.. eh

Comment: @Nick: I would say it is the point with unsigned to clearly express only positive numbers allowed. As using reference expresses non nullptr. Do you advocate against pass by reference and prefer pass by pointer to allow nullptr check? Issue is mostly when mixing signed/unsigned with conversion/promotion rules.

Comment: @Jarod42 I would agree that that's the point... whether or not that always happens in reality is another story. I dunno about you... but I have to mentor students, and, well, that ain't happening :sigh:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you’d want to at least [add a debug assertion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) `assert(a > 0)` (this will throw an exception when running the debug build of your program) in addition to the `if (a > 0) age = a;`

You can also probably throw a full-fledged exception instead of asserting when the contract is not upheld, so that the program will terminate early. You can also catch the exception at the method callsite and handle the error gracefully.

Other error handling techniques exist, and some people prefer them over exceptions, but that is out of scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

From the tag description:

> In computer science, a predicate is called an invariant to a sequence of operations provided that: if the predicate is true before starting the sequence, then it is true at the end of the sequence.

A predicate is for example `age > 0`. A sequence of operations is for example

```
setAge(42);
```

Another one

```
setAge(-123);
```

To ensure the invariant is not violated you can add a condition to `setAge`:

```
void setAge(int a) {
    if (a > 0) age = a;
}
```

It is up to you to throw an exception, terminate the program, take any other action, or just silently ignore the value when assigning it would violate the invariant. There is no "norm", because it depends on what action you want to take and what the caller can expect from passing an invalid parameter.

You could also make `age` unsigned, then the invariant `age >= 0` holds always.

Comment: Making age an unsigned integer is really a way to go here, as unsigned integer is an incorrect representation of data. Also OP should also enable signed/unsigned mismatch warnings and make the compiler treat them as errors.

Comment: @ivanmoskalev I dont fully agree. You have no control about the warning level of callers of your code. If the function takes an unsigned parameter then it has no chance to check for negatives, it would be all up to the caller to not mistakenly pass a negative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tought there is a strict way to handle invariants, for example using the `assert()`statement or throw a specific exception. But i simply need to make sure that my age can't be under 0, no matter how.

Comment: I’m sorry for a typo — i meant that unsigned integer is a _correct_representation here and signed integer isn’t. As for the impossibility of a signedness mismatch, I completely disagree here. It is super easy to create a situation where an implicit conversion will take place. Default warning settings on most c++ compilers allow for super brittle implicit code.

Comment: @ivanmoskalev you disagree with what? When you write some code you cannot force me to turn on warnings when I call it, there are better ways to disable implicit conversion between signed/unsigned

Comment: @ivanmoskalev maybe it is a misunderstanding. I took `age` being an `int` as a premise of the question. Of course making it unsigned is the easiest way to ensure `age > 0`, whether to rely on warnings then is a slightly different question and I wouldnt always count on the caller having warnings enabled

Comment: I really don’t see where the polemic comes from, since I agree with your answer, upvoted it (and I even think it better than mine which OP accepted instead). I just reiterated your point (albeit with a typo, thanks phone), and added that it will be _also_ beneficial to enable warnings. You are overreacting.

Comment: @ivanmoskalev huh, what? you wrote "... I completely disagree here." and I have no clue to what you disagree, hence I asked for clarification. What polemic? What overreaction? I am a bit confused now

Answer (score 2):

To maintain an invariant, you must establish a post-condition for all functions that could modify the state that is affected by the invariant. In your example, the invariant affects a global variable. As such, that post-condition would affect all functions, because all functions might modify the global variable. This is a problem.

The access to the state should be limited to a small set of functions that are responsible for upholding the invariant. This is often called encapsulation. An object oriented solution is to store the state in private members of a class which limits access to member functions that uphold the invariant.

As for how functions uphold the post-condition that applies to them, the implementer of the function must simply be diligent, and make sure that the state does not violate the invariant after the function returns.

In case input (i.e. parameter to the function) may influence the invariant, there are many different approaches to upholding the invariant, with various advantages and disadvantages:

1. Simply document a pre-codition that a negative number may not be passed to `setAge`. If a caller violates that contract, then the behaviour of the program may be undefined due to subsequent violation of the invariant.

   This approach can potentially be the fastest because it requires no runtime checking. But is the most error prone because it offloads the checking to the caller who might make mistakes.
2. In this particular case, an option is to use an unsigned integer type to represent the age. Since it cannot represent negative values, it works as implicit documentation, and there is no way for the caller to violate the contract.

   This approach is not applicable to all types, but can potentially be very efficient and safe in some cases.

   However in some cases, and unsigned integers in particular, this can potentially be dangerous because the programmer may do something like subtract two ages where the mathematical result would be negative, but becomes large positive value due to unsigned arithmetic. In this case, the interface would be happy because the age satisfies the pre-condition, but the behaviour might be other than what the programmer hoped for.
3. Check the input at runtime - for example using an `if` statement. If the input is bad, there are several approaches to deal with the error:

   - Throw an exception.
   - Set some default value instead of given bad value. This can be problematic because the expectation that state matches the given input does not hold.
   - Simply terminate the process.
   - Log the error in a file and possibly contact the developer directly (for example through email), but proceed with one of the other approaches, such as 1. violating the invariant, or 2. set a default value, terminate the process etc.
4. Select at compile time which of the above approaches to use. This is typically done to make more highly checking, but slower debug build, and less checking, faster build used in production. This is what the standard `assert` macro does.

All of these approaches are common, and the correct choice depends on your needs, and is to some degree subjective.